# Can I use the Web Speech API in a Chrome app?

Tags: google-chrome-app, speech-to-text

Can I use the Web Speech API in a Chrome app?

If anyone has any knowledge, please let me know. Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? Except for CSP and iframes, there aren't many limitations on Chrome Apps vs. the web platform.

Comment: Yes you can use example :https://github.com/mangini/webplatform-samples

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Apps have a special [TTS API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tts) available to them. According to [this bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=153292), the Web Speech API is not available to extensions, but it doesn't say anything about packaged apps. Your best bet is probably to just try it and see if it works.

Comment: As of Jan '15, the bug is still open. I noted on the bug comments that it also applies to Chrome Apps.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Web API section](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_other) in the chrome apps section:

> In addition to the chrome.* APIs, extensions can use all the APIs that the browser provides to web pages and apps. If the browser doesn't support an API you want to use, you can bundle additional API libraries into your extension.

Don't worry about the term 'extension' in the quote above, it seems the documentation was copied from the extensions' web api section.