# Webpage JS to Chrome App (Web Speech API)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, webspeech-api

I have a webpage that I have been testing out Googles Web Speech API on and I was looking in to creating a Chrome application that utilises this. I know for the API to work it has to be run though a webserver not from file so I don't know if a Chrome app would circumvent this and allow it to be run from the desktop. Also how would I go about transferring my HTML webpage using   into a Chrome App.

Comment: Hm. Tested it. Extensions can request permission from a tab and then it's permanent. Apps cannot and raise an error..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use the Web Speech API in a Chrome app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25960611/can-i-use-the-web-speech-api-in-a-chrome-app)